# Campos input não estão sendo preenchidos de acordo com o value

Tags: php, mysql, tabela-html, value

No meu sistema tem uma página com um formulário que cadastra um pedido e outra página com uma tabela que mostra todos os registros de pedidos cadastrados.

Em cada linha da tabela tem um pedido e um botão de edição que abre um formulário igual ao que foi usado no cadastro do pedido que deveria estar preenchido com as informações cadastradas.

Esse é o botão de edição:

```
// Adicionando botão de exclusão
    $table .= '<td><form action="FormEdicao.php" method="post">'; 
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="CLIENTE" value="'.$r['CLIENTE'].'">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SERVICO" value="'.$r['SERVICO'].'">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SOLICITACAO" value="'.$r['SOLICITACAO'].'">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="PREVISAO" value="'.$r['PREVISAO'].'">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="VALOR" value="'.$r['VALOR'].'">';
    $table .= '<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> Editar </i></button>'; //aqui está o seu botão
    $table .= '</form></td>';
}
```

Esse é o formulário de edição:

```
<?php
    require 'strcon.php';
    $query = mysqli_query($strcon, "SELECT SERVICO FROM pedidos");
    $cliente = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'CLIENTE');
    $servico = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SERVICO');
    $solicitacao = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'PREVISAO');
    $valor = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'VALOR');
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');
?>

    <!-- formulário de edição -->
    <form method="POST" action="update-ped.php">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="CLIENTE">Cliente:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CLIENTE" name="CLIENTE" value="<?php echo $cliente; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="SERVICO">Serviço:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SERVICO" name="SERVICO" value="<?php echo $servico; ?>">
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="SOLICITACAO">Data de solicitação:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SOLICITACAO" name="SOLICITACAO" value="<?php echo $solicitacao; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="PREVISAO">Data prevista:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PREVISAO" name="PREVISAO" value="<?php echo $previsao; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="VALOR">Valor:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="VALOR" name="VALOR" value="<?php echo $valor; ?>">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Mas por algum motivo esses campos que deveriam estar preenchidos não estão, segue imagens pra facilitar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como esta seu botão editar?

Comment: Meu botão de editar é um href normal que redireciona pra página de edição.

Comment: Vou colocar meu botão de edição na pergunta.

Comment: Cara, o problema era o botão de edição, os names estavam errados, você estava certo.

Answer (score 1):

ola; salvar e editar seguem logicas um tanto diferentes;
tente assim, resumidamente:

1 - sua tabela deve ter uma coluna chave primaria
(vamos chama-la de id);

2 - vc precisa passar esse id referente ao registro selecionado
 normalmente pelo metodo GET e vc devera declarar
uma variavel referente a esse id;
ex:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

(pesquise sobre **querystrings**);

3 - sua consulta ao banco de dados deverá utilizar esse id com a clausula where
ex:

```
$consulta=select * from tabela where id=$id;
```

4- sua variavel $consulta devera ser um comando mysqli_query; ex:

```
mysqli->query($strcon,"SELECT * FROM tabela where id=$id");
```

5- recupere os registros usando fetch

```
while($row = $consulta->fetch_array()){
```

6- exiba a coluna dentro do "value" do formulario;
ex:

```
input type="text" class="form-control" id="SOLICITACAO" name="SOLICITACAO" value="<?php echo $row['solicitacao']; ?>">
```

7 - ex do botao:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: location.href='detalhes_noticia.php?id=<?php
echo $lista1->id?>';" value="Clique Aqui" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Com base nessas informações não tem como dar uma resposta definitiva, porém o que posso te ajudar é ajudar a entender o que está ocorrendo para tomar uma ação.

Precisamos saber se os dados da query que estão no formulário onde tem o botão "Editar" estão sendo enviados via POST para essa outra página em questão.

Para isso clique com o botão direito do mouse em cima do botão "Editar" e clique em "inspecionar". Vai abrir uma outra janela do navegador que são as ferramentas de desenvolvedor, nessa janela na parte superior tem um botão chamado "Network" e lá você deixa marcado a opção "Preserve log".

Obs.: Se essa janela de Ferramentas do desenvolvedor" abrir na mesma janela que está usando, você pode abrir separado como mostro na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora quando você clicar no botão "Editar" na página do site através dessa aba "Network" você poderá ver no painel do lado direito as informações da requisição inclusive os dados enviados via POST, veja um exemplo na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essas dicas para utilizar a Ferramenta para desenvolvedores eu exemplifiquei utilizando o Google Chrome, também existe nos outros navegadores mas talvez tenha um nome ou jeito de entrar um pouco diferente, se usa outro é só dar uma pesquisada.

Outra coisa prática para tentar entender o problema é você dar um echo nas variáveis que recebem os valores via POST para ver se estão vindo vazias.

Espero que lhe ajude!

Até mais!